# compare two columns from different tables and append values for matching rows to first file

Tags: awk

I am trying to add plain text passwords to there corresponding rows in an exported user table.  I have two files:

usertable

```
    barry  hash1
    fred   hash2
    mary   hash3
    rich   hash2
```

crackpasstable

```
    ptpass1 hash1
    ptpass2 hash2
```

I want the output to look like:

combintedtable

```
    barry  hash1  ptpass1
    fred   hash2  ptpass2
    mary   hash3
    rich   hash2  ptpass2
```

I have tried the below code based on another entry I found but this only prints out rows that have matches, not all of them:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$0; next} a[$2]>0{print a[$2],$1}' usertable crackpasstable > combinedtable
```

I want to try to print out all the rows in the usertable (hopefully in the original order) and just add matching passwords in a new column if I was able to crack them.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**pr.awk:**

```
# Usage:
# awk -f pr.awk crackpasstable usertable > combintedtable

BEGIN {
   ct = ARGV[1]
   ARGV[1] = "" # read ARGV[1] file implicitly, ARGV[2] file
                # explicitly
   while (getline < ct > 0) {
       p = $1
       h = $2
       phash[h] = p
    }
}

{
   h = $2
   if (h in phash)
       print $0 "  " phash[h]
    else
       print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are almost right. read in `crackpasstable`, then scan `usertable` and add pass from the loaded file

```
# read in the first file
FNR == NR {
    hashes [$2] = $1 # hopefully, there are no repeating hash values
    next
}

# scan all other files
$2 in hashes {
    $0 = $0 "\t" hashes[$2]
}

1 # or {print} if you prefer to be explicit
```

USAGE:

```
> ThisScript crackpasstable usertable
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1;next} {print ($2 in a) ? $0"\t"a[$2] : $0}' crackpasstable usertable
```